# reliable process to add text on top of existing text-file

Tags: text, vbscript, addition

I know how to add text on top a text file but what I need is a way to ensure that at the point of reading the "old-text" no other process add text to that file. Imagine there exist one log file which will be fed on text from other processes. My current process is using FSO in two steps. The first step Open the text in "read" mode then grab the whole content with `.ReadAll` and close the file afterwards. The next step is to open this file in "write" mode and add new text on top of the old Content and close the file.

My problem is that at the moment when I read the whole content another process could write at this time an additional log-entry (which I could not grab). This results in losing the log-entry from the other process. Below is my current workaround...

```
Dim strContentsOLD, sNewLogEntry
Dim sPFnStartLogGol : sPFnStartLogGol = "C:\Path\to\logfile.txt"
Dim oFSO            : Set oFSO        = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oLogfile        : Set oLogfile = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sPFnStartLogGol, 1, True)            'ForReading = 1 / True = create new if not exist
If IsObject(oLogfile) Then                                                                      'already open for Reading
    If oFSO.GetFile(sPFnStartLogGol).Size > 0 Then strContentsOLD = oLogfile.ReadAll            'read all old log-entries
    oLogfile.Close                                                                              'close log-file
    sNewLogEntry = "This is a new Log entry"                                                    'log entry
    Set oLogfile = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sPFnStartLogGol, 2)                                        'open again but ForWriting = 2 
    oLogFile.write sNewLogEntry & vbCrLf & strContentsOLD                                       'add old entries underneath new entry
    oLogFile.close
End If
```

Comment: What language you are using? Please add that to the tags.

Comment: Have you tried using ADODB.Stream?  You could specify Position=0, then use Write or WriteText to add your text to the top of the existing text file.

Comment: Hi leeharvey1, sorry for late reply. No I haven´t. I am not familiar with ADODB. Do you have a small code for that?.

Comment: @leeharvey1 will that help if the file is constantly being updated? Don't think what the OP is asking for is possible with VBScript.